# Access and change of the value of a css pseudoclass via code in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to access css pseudo-classes such as `.text-area *.text {}` and more importantly change values of them via code?
`textArea.setStyle()` does not seem to be applicable in this case.
To describe the problem: 
I'm trying to change the text-alignment of an TextArea on a button click. 
I know it's possible to change the alignment via

```
.text-area *.text {
-fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

but how can i bind that to a button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there are no pseudoclasses used in the CSS selector `.text-area *.text`

The selector parts used are class selectors (`.text`, `.text-area`), the universal selector (`*`) and the descendant selector ( between `.text-area` and `*.text`).

However there are multiple ways to set the alignment from code:

#### Using a Pseudo-class

A pseudoclass could be used to distinguish centered `TextArea`s from non-centered ones.

```
PseudoClass centered = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("centered");

// activate pseudoclass
textArea.pseudoClassStateChanged(centered, true);

// deactivate pseudoclass
textArea.pseudoClassStateChanged(centered, false);
```

CSS

```css
.text-area:centered .text {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Similarly a class could be used, but it's less convenient, since classes could be added multiple times.

#### Using a custom CSS variable

Values of CSS variables are inherited from parent nodes, which is why you could use it to assign a property of a child node using inline style:

CSS

```css
.text-area {
    /* default value of variable */
    alignment: left;
}

.text-area .text {
    /* use variable for TextArea child */
    -fx-text-alignment: alignment;
}
```

```
// overwrite variable from inline style
textArea.setStyle("alignment: center;");
```

#### Finding the `Node`s using `lookupAll`

This is the worst alternative, since it requires `Control`s like `TextArea` to have their `skin` created, which does not happen until layout, which means the code won't work until the first layout pass.

```
// find children matching .text and assign set the property for each one
textArea.lookupAll(".text").forEach(n -> n.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center;"));
```